# Watson's Lemma and Laplace transformation

Tags: asymptotics

Use Watson's lemma to find the expansion of $$F(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \lambda t} sin(t)dt$$
,and verfify the answer using Laplace transformation by expanding the answer using Taylor's expansion.

Comparing the above integral with $$F(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \lambda t} f(t)dt.$$

For applying Watson's lemma we need $f(0) \neq 0$, in our case it is $f(0)=0.$ So I integrated by parts before applying Watson's Lemma: $$F(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{- \lambda t}\ cos(t) \ dt \sim \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\lambda^{n+1}} \sim \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\lambda^{n+1}} $$

Using **Laplace transform:**
$$F(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \lambda t} sin(t)dt = \frac{1}{1+ \lambda^{2}} = \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^{2n}}$$

**My Question**

I am not able to figure out where I am making mistakes as I am getting different answers with two different methods. Can someone figure out my mistake?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(t)=\cos(t)$, then

$$\begin{align}
f'(t)&=-\sin(t)\\\\
f''(t)&=-\cos(t)\\\\
f'''(t)&=\sin(t)\\\\
f''''(t)&=\cos(t)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for each odd integer $n$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n/2}$ for each even integer $n$.

Can you apply Watson's Lemma now?

Comment: The only term that is not matching is for $\lambda$. @mark

Comment: $$F(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{- \lambda t}\ cos(t) \ dt \sim \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\lambda^{n+1}} \\ \sim \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0,2,4, \cdot \cdot}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{\lambda^{n+1}} \\  \sim \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0 }^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\lambda^{2n+1}} \\  \sim \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \sum_{n=0 }^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\lambda^{2n}}  $$

Comment: All terms match now.  For the first series you wrote replace $\lambda^{n+1}$ with $\lambda^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Yes.  You have it now!  Well done.

Comment: Apart from that, everything in my process is right?

Comment: Yes.  Your methodology is correct.  And you have the correct result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115239/discussion-between-atul-anurag-sharma-and-mark-viola).